# Операторы php web

Tags: php, операторы

Здравстуйте, что означает этот оператор в языке PHP `->`? Погуглил, не нашел ничего. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обращения к полям и методам объекта.
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.object.php

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо

Comment: @Juicy отметьте вопрос как решённый - засчитайте ответ.